# Why do we hold contacts for a day in Journey Builder? What if we set it to 1 hour?

Tags: journeybuilder

We have a journey that repeats every morning to check for new status changes.

By default, there is a wait period of 1 day before the end of any journey - why?
Obviously, if the automation runs every 24 hours, those who are held might miss the next-day's run.

Flow Control best practices mention to avoid less than 1 hour waits:
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_bp_flow_control_best_practices.htm&type=5

So, our logic is to change the 1 day last wait to liberate them after 1 hour.

Any insights?

Thanks!

Comment: whats your use case to change this? do you have re-entry only after exiting?

Comment: @EazyE - We can assume re-entry only after exiting. 

The question is - what's the use case to keep this? 
We all agree you wouldn't keep contacts in a journey just for fun intuitively. 
There must be a valid reason someone conceived it - it's to work around something. And I bet it has something to do with report-back to SFDC / update of journey goals or Cache.

Comment: when contacts come off wait steps they are processed by the same queue as other contacts, so setting this to say 1 min could have performance impact since you are evaluating each contact multiple times quickly one time to go into the wait step and one time to exit the journey. This is also why there is a recommendation to not have a 1 min wait at the beginning of the journey. Unless you have a use case to get subscribers out of a journey for re-entry concerns this value can be left alone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One valid reason I could think of is to allow Contacts to sync from Salesforce for Journey Goal / Exit stats.

For example, if a goal is to have an action that is reflected in the CRM - such as a status change (convert), we'd need to keep them in the journey for Goal reporting.

Since sync can be 15 minutes or more, keeping them for 24 hours is reasonably Safe.
Obviously if we end the journey right away, the goals / exit criteria related to updates in the CRM will never be met.

Comment: Yep the 24hr default might just be for "safety" as you say. But then going back to your original use case, this creates problems as you are repeating the journey every 24hrs and contacts can only re-enter after exiting. I still can't think of any particular reason that is HAS to be 24hrs. You obviously just have to design and setup the journey in a way that works for your use case.

Answer (score 1):

There is no particular reason as far as I know. It is just the default setting.

We have changed ours to one hour and even one minute in some cases. It works fine.

One thing to note is that if you are entering a large number of contacts all at once into the journey, it will take some time to process. So even though you entered them all at the same time, they would not progress through the journey at the same time. Not sure if this has any impact on your use case.

Comment: Thanks for the insight @Ben. Glad to see you see no impact when changing this. But there must be a valid reason for this addition - report back to SFDC giving enough time to SFMC to update journey goals? update SFMC reporting? cache? avoid double-sends in some way? 
Something ! :)

Comment: I can tell you from experience there are many many things in Marketing Cloud that are setup is a very illogical way or are just plain dumb. So I wouldn't bet on this having any specific reasoning behind it :)

Comment: hmmm... I just posted one valid reason for keeping them in the answer below. In many use cases (i.e. if you don't define Goals/Exit Criteria) this reason doesn't apply.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the second last activity before the 1 day wait period to edit contact add toggle a flag in a data extension. Then include that flag in the exit criteria. Cheers